# Creating a numbered element with vanilla js

Tags: javascript, dom, slider, innerhtml

I am using the dom to create some html elements. Button to be exact. I am pretty new to javascript so any advice would be appreciated.

The js I am using for this is based on a nodelist of divs. I am using a for loop to create buttons that are based on each object in the nodelist (each div spawns a button).

Here is the js:

```js
let indInit = function(){
 for(i = 0; i < slides.length; i++){
  document.querySelector('.gallery-indicator-nav').innerHTML +=
  '<button class="gallery-indicator" onclick="currentSlide(1)></button>';
 }
};
indInit();
```

Obviously, I end up with

```html
<div class="gallery-indicator-nav">
<button class="gallery-indicator" onclick="currentSlide(1)></button>
<button class="gallery-indicator" onclick="currentSlide(1)></button>
<button class="gallery-indicator" onclick="currentSlide(1)></button>
</div>
```

I would like my buttons to generate like this:

```html
<div class="gallery-indicator-nav">
<button class="gallery-indicator" onclick="currentSlide(1)></button>
<button class="gallery-indicator" onclick="currentSlide(2)></button>
<button class="gallery-indicator" onclick="currentSlide(3)></button>
</div>
```

I am assuming I need to use some sort or math object and concatenation but research on google has been confusing to say the least. I figure there must be a simple solution =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using `innerHTML` you can treat it like any other strings, so:

```
***.innerHTML = 'xxxxxxx' + i + 'xxxxxx';
```

can be used;

Maybe you want to try to create the button element and attach an EventListener:

```
btn = document.createElement(....);
btn.addEventListener( .... );
```

Comment: Sweet. Thank you Terry Wu! The first suggestion did the trick. I had a sneaky feeling this wasn't that complicated. Thank you for your help and time, Terry!

Answer (score 0):

After Terry Wu's suggestion:

```js
for(i = 0; i < slides.length; i++){
 document.querySelector('.gallery-indicator-nav').innerHTML +=
 '<button class="gallery-indicator" onclick="currentSlide(' + i + ')"></button>';
}
```

I ended up with this. Perfect:

```html
<div class="gallery-indicator-nav">
  <button class="gallery-indicator" onclick="currentSlide(0)"></button>
  <button class="gallery-indicator" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></button>
  <button class="gallery-indicator" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></button>
</div>
```